# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/zzc.class

Tags: android, gradle

I imported my project and since then I have been getting this error.
There is no error when I just build the project or use 'sync project with gradle files' option.
I am getting this error while trying to build the apk:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/zzc.class

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mahe.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

  dependencies {
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
 {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'maven'

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}
```

this is the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        apply plugin: 'maven'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you set `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'` ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yes I did.

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have edited my question to include build.gradle code

Answer (score 0):

Please refer: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies

You must use FirebaseUI version **2.2.0** (not 0.6.2) with Firebase/GooglePlay version 11.0.4

---

By the way, you can also remove this section from the `app/build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did what u asked
probably that solved it but gave me another error
please help me out with this:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
 is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.

Comment: Did you do what it says? `Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: yeah it doesnt change anythimg
and removing the maven repository gives a lot of errors

Comment: Removing the repository was a suggestion (but from only one file)